# why my hidden div is not appearing by button click?

Tags: asp.net

i have a asp button in my userpage.aspx and after clicking the button my hidden div will appear..but it's not appearing???

my userpage.aspx

```
 <asp:Button ID="addtutorial" runat="server" Text="Add Tutorial" OnClientClick=" return addtutorial();"/>
```

my css

```
#addtudiv
{
width:170px;
height:190px;
border:1px solid green;
position:relative;
left:550px;
top:-330px;
background-color:#ffffff;
border:5px solid #182032;
display:none;

}
```

my javascript

```
 function addtutorial() {

      $("#addtudiv").toggle();
      return false;
  }
```

don't know why javascript function not working??

Comment: your css and js use `#addtudiv` but your HTML has the ID as `#addtutorial`...?

Comment: You might be needing `ClientIdMode="Static"`

Comment: by clicking the button i am trying to show my hidden addtudiv...

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering... why you wrote

```
top:-330px;
```

in your CSS class? Maybe the button appears, but its position is not in a visible part of the page.

Another possible issue: you're referencing your component with #addtudiv in jquery and css, but button's id is "addtutorial"

Comment: by clicking the button i want to show this hidden div...

Comment: I see. But isn't top:-300px moving your div outside the viewport of your browser? I mean, maybe your div is in the dom but you can't see it because it's "over your monitor". In order to check, try your browser's dom inspector and check if you div has display:block or display:none after clicking the button

Comment: i found the problem...it was not the top:-300px..actually the button has the same id name that is the function name also...

Answer (score 0):

try with a checkbox :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MsCheckBox").change(function () {
            if ( !this.checked) {
                $("#ParametrageMS").css("display", "none"); 
            } else
            {
                $("#ParametrageMS").css("display", "block"); 
            }

        })
    });
```

it's a part of code that i use for one of my programs and it works good.
I think that in your Javascript you must specify the css `display` is `none` or `block`

Answer (score 0):

i made a mistake of declaring the id and the function name same...that's the problem actually..

Comment: @chadocat Lol, you bot. Read the answer first and then flag it as "not an answer".